# select dropdown value and use in a sql select

Tags: javascript, mysqli

I have a dynamic dropdown list which is working -

```
<form action="" name="myform" id="myform" method="post">                      
<div>
<strong>Show Asset Type</strong>
<select name="assettypeid" id="assettypeid" onchange="typechanged();">

<sql:query var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/icantrack">
SELECT id, name FROM assettype order by name
</sql:query>

 <option value="1">-- All Asset Types--</option>
 <c:forEach var="row" items="${queryresults.rows}">
 <option value="<c:out value="${row.id}"/>"
 <c:if test="${row.id == param.assettypeid}">
      <c:out value="selected"/>
 </c:if>
 ><c:out value="${row.name}" />
 </option>
 </c:forEach>
 </select>

 </div> 
 </form>
```

And I know I can determine the selected value using javascript -

```
function typechanged()
    {
         typechosen = document.getElementById("assettypeid").value;
```

But I want to then use typechosen in a separate sql select further down in the jsp (and therefore a javascript variable is useless)

I believe my options are -

POST - but this (in my case) has to be back to the same jsp and I don't want anything to append anything to the URL (as my page will then no longer display). I may have to use GET as I don't want silly "are you sure you want to send the same data again" messages from the browser.

mysql fetch object - but all the examples of this don't seem to work?

Something else (that's simple and which I am not seeing?

I need to be able to 'store' the selected value of the dropdown and then recover / use it in another select i.e. -

where assettypeid like <%=typechosen%>

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the value of assettypeid field on the post request, actually this is not done by JavaScript, it is by server-side.
And you don't need the onchange="typechanged();"

Sample code is as follow:

```
<c:when test="${empty param.assettypeid }">
    <select name="assettypeid" id="assettypeid">

    <sql:query var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/icantrack">
    SELECT id, name FROM assettype order by name
    </sql:query>

     <option value="1">-- All Asset Types--</option>
     <c:forEach var="row" items="${queryresults.rows}">
     <option value="<c:out value="${row.id}"/>"
     <c:if test="${row.id == param.assettypeid}">
          <c:out value="selected"/>
     </c:if>
     <c:out value="${row.name}" />
     </option>
     </c:forEach>
     </select>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    Hello <b><c:out value="${param.assettypeid}" /></b>!
</c:otherwise>
```

Comment: Thanks York, can you be more specific (how exactly do I get and retrieve assettypeid without using javascript to determine the selected value)

Comment: Post, which is the only option which doesn't append to the url causes silly resend messages from the browser.

Comment: Hi Ralph, answer is updated. This is how to get parameter in JSTL for server side. "Post" request doesn't pass parameters in url but you can still get the value by code.

Comment: Thanks, fails as no choose and you still show typechanged(), is this still required? Please keep helping.

Comment: Hello <b><c:out value="${param.assettypeid}" /></b>! doesn't produce anything?